# JAXB with XPATH Flexibility to modify Objects at runtime

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jaxb

I want to modify JAXB loaded objects (from XML) so that i can marshall them back to the disk with updated XML.

Now lets take an example:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer id="1" name="Jack">
    <Address type="Residence">
      <FirstLine>1 saxon Court</FirstLine>
      <City>CY</City>
    </Address>
  </Customer>
    <Customer id="2" name="Iain">
    <Address type="Residence">
      <FirstLine>104 Bank Road</FirstLine>
      <City>NY</City>
    </Address>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Now as I have multiple customers, I want to use XPATH functionality to get the handle of the  `Customer[@id=2]` object where I can add/update an address.
If I will not use the XPATH like functionality then JAXB generated classes will have "L`ist<Customer> customer`" and I will have to iterate through the list of customer to match with my desirable `Customer[@id=2]`.

Can anyone give me idea how to get the Object instance handle for the JAXB generated objects using XPATH, so I can marshall it back to update the actual XML on the disk.
If it cannot be done through JAXB, then what can be alternative solution to read and write XMLs using java Objects with XPATH flexibility.

Updated Question with Sample code:

Following is the sample code which shows what i want to achieve with Moxy/JAXB.

```
package org.soc.test.customers.moxy;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class UnmarshalDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext jc =    (org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext)     JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        File instanceDoc = new File("input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller() .unmarshal(instanceDoc);
        List<PhoneNumber>  phones = jc.getValueByXPath(customer, "phone-number[@id=\"12\"]", null, List.class);
        String customerId = jc.getValueByXPath(customer, "@id", null, String.class);
        System.out.println("Customerid " + customerId + "  ,  phone " + (phones==null?"0":phones.size()));
        jc.setValueByXPath(customer, "phone-number[@id=\"12\"]/area-code/text()", null, "555");
    jc.createMarshaller().marshal(customer, System.out);
    }
}
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer id="1141">
    <first-name>Jon</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
    <phone-number id="11">
        <area-code>515</area-code>
        <number>2726652</number>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number id="12">
        <area-code>515</area-code>
        <number>2726652</number>
    </phone-number>
</customer>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     elementFormDefault="unqualified"
     attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="first-name" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
                <xs:element name="last-name" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
                <xs:element ref="phone-number" maxOccurs="2"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="phone-number">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="area-code" type="stringMaxSize5"/>
                <xs:element name="number" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="stringMaxSize5">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="5"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

jaxb.properties:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Output:
Customerid 1141  ,  phone 0

I am expecting the list size of the phone number to be 1 but it is returning null.

Hope this helps in understanding about the problem that I facing.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath 1.0 queries on JAXB objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091354/xpath-1-0-queries-on-jaxb-objects)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me the link. I already tried with Moxy but with Unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: I have modified the question for better understanding of the problem that I am facing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported with Moxy. The `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context` only supports numeric indexes in square brackets. While the `XPathFragment` understands it and creates appropriate predicates, the `Context` ignores those as far as searching for a match goes. I'd either raise a bug, or look for another tool.

See the [`Context`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/eclipselink/eclipselink.runtime.git/tree/foundation/org.eclipse.persistence.core/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/Context.java#n371) source code (Commit `7cedaac6cdf9384ae9a06129d6f9abd607f9e3c4`, Line 371 onwards) for exactly what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. As we know that JAXB unable to support full  xpath functionalities, please can someone suggest me what are the other alternatives/api  that I can use for this requirement? Ideally I would like to have both Object level access and XPATH flexibility when dealing with XML.